# Revtex - using math in footnote

Tags: math-mode, footnotes, revtex

How one can use  mathematics in footnote using ReVteX?
I have a particular problem with `\rangle`

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb, prl]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

TEST\footnote{footnote with math $ \langle X \rangle$ }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Congrats on this nice little, really minimal working example. We don't see such here too often by new users.

Comment: thnx! I was really in a puzzle, with the footnote..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens only when the footnotes are inserted in the reference section. The problem is that `\langle` becomes written as `\delimiter "426830A` (and similarly for `\rangle`.

Those double quotes confuse the BibTeX parser.

There are a few strategies available:

1. Safest. Enclose the math into `\unexpanded`:

   ```
   \footnote{footnote with math \unexpanded{$ \langle X \rangle$}}
   ```
2. Safe. Use `\protect` before commands that can go after `\left` and `\right`

   ```
   \footnote{footnote with math $\protect\langle X \protect\rangle$}
   ```
3. Hack. Enclose the math in braces.

Comment: Yes, now it is working. Thanks for all solutions!!

Answer (score 7):

Often helps, and here as well:

- If something surprisingly doesn't work, put it into a box :-)

  ```
  \footnote{footnote with math \mbox{$ \langle X \rangle$}}
  ```

  (Version: if line breaks don't work, use `\parbox`)
- If something with BibTeX doesn't work, try putting it into braces:

  ```
  \footnote{footnote with math {$ \langle X \rangle$}}
  ```

Both ways work here. Simple braces are preferable.

[image: Footnote with REVTeX]

Note for readers who test: BibTeX is required for footnotes with REVTeX.

Comment: Even just putting the math inside curly braces does the job.  (I.e., the \mbox can be omitted.)