# biber eating \langle and \rangle commands

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber

I have some entries in my reference list that contain `\langle` and `\rangle` signs in their title like the one in the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{test,
author = {A. Uthor},
title = {A title with some $\langle \Psi \rangle $ stuff},
year = {2014},
publisher = {A Company}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I process this MWE with `pdflatex` and `biber` the `\langle`s and `\rangle`s are missing in the output and the `pdflatex log file says

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:⟨ not set up for use with LaTeX.

and

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:⟩ not set up for use with LaTeX.

[image]

I already have tried the tricks from [Revtex - using math in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94858/18674) without any success. When looking into the `.bbl` file generated by biber it turns out, that the title field looks as follows:

```
\field{title}{A title with some $⟨\Psi ⟩$ stuff}
```

So obviously biber itself is already replacing the `\langle` and `\rangle` commands with `⟨` and `⟩` respectively but those are then incompatible with `inputenc`.

According to the `biblatex` manual I could set the `safeinputenc` package option which instructs `biber` to try to convert all utf8 encoded stuff into ASCII. This works for the issue described above but it will also cause me new pain with other entries as some of the conversions that `biber` *tries* are leading to wrong results.

So is there some third way that I don't see or am I maybe experiencing a bug in `biber` as its conversion to `⟨` and `⟩` is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this works for everything - it did however work for the cases I used and the above. From the `biber` help page:

> ```
> --decodecharsset=[recode set name]
>     The set of characters included in the conversion routine when
>     decoding LaTeX macros into UTF-8 (which happens when
>     --bblencoding|-E is set to UTF-8). Set to "full" to try harder with
>     a much larger set or "base" to use a smaller basic set. Default is
>     "base". You may want to try "full" if you have less common UTF-8
>     characters in your data source. The recode sets are defined in the
>     reencoding data file which can be customised. See the --recodedata
>     option and the PDF manual.
> ```

I however do not know and undersatnd why this worked in this case, but if you run

```
biber --decodecharsset=full <main[.bcf]>
```

instead of writing

```
\field{labeltitle}{A title with some $⟨\Psi ⟩$ stuff}
\field{title}{A title with some $⟨\Psi ⟩$ stuff}
```

to `main.bbl` it will write the desired

```
\field{labeltitle}{A title with some $\langle \Psi \rangle$ stuff}
\field{title}{A title with some $\langle \Psi \rangle$ stuff}
```

and hence latex will not complain about not knowing chars. This might be more useful if there are a couple of unknown characters in your database.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it really addresses the issue instead of providing a workaround. I came hear when biber was constantly replacing `\'\{\i}` with `í`, a unicode character unavailable in computer modern fonts. Invoking with biber with **--decodecharsset=null** fixes the issue.

Answer (score 16):

It seems that Biber tries to be smarter than LaTeX. ;-) Perhaps there's a BibLaTeX/Biber way, but a workaround is easy to find. We just define the characters `inputenc` doesn't know.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{test,
  author = {A. Uthor},
  title = {A title with some $\langle \Psi \rangle $ stuff},
  year = {2014},
  publisher = {A Company},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⟨}{\langle}
\newunicodechar{⟩}{\rangle}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]